# Setting one range of cells equal to another without losing current selections

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fill a range of cells with the contents of another range of cells without losing the current selection(s), using VBA for Excel on Mac.

Why does

```
  Sheets("FormView").Range("C3") = Sheets("DataView").Range("E3")
```

work, but

```
  Sheets("FormView").Range("C3:D10") = Sheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10")
```

fail?

Can you suggest alternatives, please?

I could save the current selections and reselect them, but that would be admitting defeat...

Comment: You do not need any selection for doing that... Try `Sheets("FormView").Range(“C3:D10”).value = Sheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10").value`.  Excel 'understands' somehow what you try doing and will accept your way, too, but take care of the used double quotes... They work if the number of columns and rows of both ranges are the same and in your example they are.

Comment: `Sheets("FormView").Range("C3:D10") = Sheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10")` works fine

Comment: What does *fail* mean? Your worksheets are not qualified, so whatever you're doing will behave differently if different workbooks are selected (active). Try: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FormView").Range("C3:D10").Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10").Value`, which refers to the workbook containing this code. These long lines are hard to read so I would suggest you use variables.

Comment: FaneDuru, that gives "compile error: Expected: list separator or )."

Comment: VBasic2008, fail means the cells remain blank.  Your suggestion gives "Run-time error '9'.  Subscript out of range."

Comment: That information is useless without the name of the procedure and the line that is highlighted when the error occurs. A wild guess would be that the code is 'looking' for the worksheets in the wrong workbook mentioned in my previous comment i.e. you could replace `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` or better put the code in a standard module of the workbook containing the worksheets. Also, I have accidentally mixed up the ranges. Oops. Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: @rowan Fanes commented solution does work, if you fix the quotes around `“C3:D10”` to `"C3:D10"` (the bogus quotes were probably copied from your original post, which were probably introduced by your browser and not part of your actual code).

Comment: @chris neilsen, Yes!  Thank you very, very much.

Comment: @FaneDuru, sorry for being obtuse, I'd screwed up the quotes somehow.
Many thanks, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be as neat as you like (and might be admitting your defeat a bit) but I'd copy the data without changing selection:

```
Sheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10").Copy
Sheets("FormView").Range("C3:D10").PasteSpecial
```

The selection will stay where it is but if you go to the "FormView" tab, it will have C3:D10 selected.

Comment: Алексей Р, not for me: the cells remain blank.

Comment: Lord_Lucan, for me the receiving cells remain blank. Sigh.

Comment: And now I must go away for the weekend.  Thanks for your suggestions, guys.  Sorry I seem to be a lost cause!

Answer (score -1):

### Copy Range Values by Assignment

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRange()
    
    Const sName As String = "DataView"
    Const sAddress As String = "E3:F10"
    
    Const dName As String = "FormView"
    Const dFirst As String = "C3"
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sAddress)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value

End Sub

Sub CopyRangeNoConstants()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("DataView")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("E3:F10")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("FormView")
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range("C3")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value

End Sub

Sub CopyRangeNoConstantsNoWorksheets()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets("DataView").Range("E3:F10")
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = wb.Worksheets("FormView").Range("C3")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value

End Sub
```